# Managing GitLab CI/CD scan jobs in a centralized template file for multiple projects

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Under devops repo I have `scans.yml` file (`devops/gitlab-templates/code-scans/scans.yml`), which suppose to contain multiple code scans. Currently I scan with `Checkov` and `Snyk`, but I want to add more scans in the future.

This is the `scans.yml` file:

```
checkov:
  stage: checkov
  image: python:3.9
  script:
    - echo "SCANNING checkov"
    - echo "-----------------------------"
    - pip install checkov >/dev/null
    - checkov -d . --quiet --soft-fail --check HIGH --bc-api-key $BC_API_KEY --include-all-checkov-policies --run-all-external-checks 

snyk:
  image: node:latest
  stage: snyk
  script:
    - echo "SCANNING snyk"
    - echo "-----------------------------"
    - npm install -g npm@latest
    - npm install -g snyk
    # Run snyk help, snyk auth, snyk monitor, snyk test to break build and out report
    - snyk --help
    - snyk auth $SNYK_TOKEN
    - snyk test
```

I have about 10 projects, and I want implement those scans when merging to `main` branch. This is how I implement it in each project:

```
include:
  - project: "<org>/devops"
    ref: "main"
    file: "/gitlab-templates/code-scans/scans.yml"

stages:
  - checkov
  - snyk

checkov:
  only:
    - main

snyk:
  only:
    - main
```

The problem is when I will want to add or remove scan, it will force me to edit `.gitlab-ci.yml` in all projects - which will take long time.

**Is there a way to manage the scans in `scans.yml` file, and to call those scans only once for each project?**

---

I tried few things, but none of them worked. This is one thing that I tried - in the `scans.yml` file

```
checkov:
  stage: checkov
  image: python:3.9
  script:
    - echo "SCANNING checkov"
    - echo "-----------------------------"
    - pip install checkov >/dev/null
    - checkov -d . --quiet --soft-fail --check HIGH --bc-api-key $BC_API_KEY --include-all-checkov-policies --run-all-external-checks 

snyk:
  image: node:latest
  stage: snyk
  script:
    - echo "SCANNING snyk"
    - echo "-----------------------------"
    - npm install -g npm@latest
    - npm install -g snyk
    # Run snyk help, snyk auth, snyk monitor, snyk test to break build and out report
    - snyk --help
    - snyk auth $SNYK_TOKEN
    - snyk test 
   needs: [checkov]

 scans:
   stage: release
   needs: [snyk]
```

And in app project to add:

```
include:
  - project: "<org>/devops"
    ref: "main"
    file: "/gitlab-templates/code-scans/scans.yml"

stages:
  - scans

scans:
  only:
    - main
```

Comment: Does your project contain any other job besides the one designed for the scans?

Comment: @bhito In the future - yes

Answer (score 0):

You can add another layer of templating to your jobs so you just need to modify a single file and all of the projects importing it will have the changes applied. Right now with just a couple of jobs it may sound a bit redundant but if you add more in the future it will allow you to have more flexibility on your pipelines - I'm currently using this approach as we have 20+ projects and it comes very handy to propagate changes.

With this strategy your setup will look like this:

This is your previous `scan jobs file`:

```yaml
    checkov:
      stage: checkov
      image: python:3.9
      script:
        - echo "SCANNING checkov"
        - echo "-----------------------------"
        - pip install checkov >/dev/null
        - checkov -d . --quiet --soft-fail --check HIGH --bc-api-key $BC_API_KEY --include-all-checkov-policies --run-all-external-checks 
    
    snyk:
      image: node:latest
      stage: snyk
      script:
        - echo "SCANNING snyk"
        - echo "-----------------------------"
        - npm install -g npm@latest
        - npm install -g snyk
        # Run snyk help, snyk auth, snyk monitor, snyk test to break build and out report
        - snyk --help
        - snyk auth $SNYK_TOKEN
        - snyk test 
       needs: [checkov]
    
     scans:
       stage: release
       needs: [snyk]
```

And the generic template - you can have it on the same repo or in a separate one but I like to keep these files together:

```
include:
      - project: "<org>/devops"
        ref: "main" # I prefer using refs over local, as you can use branches for versioning and test changes
        file: "specific-pipelines/security-scans.gitlab-ci.yml"
stages:
      - scans
```

Below there's a sample on how your repo may be reorganised

```
org/devops repo
├── generic-template.gitlab-ci.yml
├── specific-pipelines
│   ├── security-scans.gitlab-ci.yml
```

Finally on your app project add:

```yaml
    include:
      - project: "<org>/devops"
        ref: "main"
        file: "generic-template.gitlab-ci.yml"
    
    
    scans:
      only:
        - main
```

With this adding or removing jobs to your pipeline is as easy as commenting or removing the imports from the generic template. As I mentioned, with just 1 import it may look redundant, but it allows you to extend your setup easily in the future and even test changes on your pipelines.